# Move/adjust content according to a phone's screen size in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have written a simple calculator app in Flutter, this is the code (I haven't included the buttons.dart file):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
}

var userQuestion = '';
var userAnswer = '';

var userQuestion2 = '';
var userAnswer2 = '';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final myTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.teal[300]);

  final List<String> buttons = [
    'C',
    'DEL',
    '%',
    '÷',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '×',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '-',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '+',
    '0',
    '.',
    'ANS',
    '=',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[100],
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(userQuestion,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.teal[900])),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      userAnswer,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.teal[900]),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: GridView.builder(
                  primary: false,
                  itemCount: buttons.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    // Clear Button
                    if (index == 0) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userQuestion = '';
                            userAnswer = '';
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.green,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }

                    // Delete Button
                    else if (index == 1) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userQuestion = userQuestion.substring(
                                0, userQuestion.length - 1);
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }

                    // Equal Button
                    else if (index == buttons.length - 1) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            equalPressed();
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.teal[300],
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }

                    // ANS Button
                    else if (index == 18) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          var temp = userQuestion.length + userAnswer.length;
                          if (temp >= 17) {
                            setState(() {
                              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text(
                                      'Maximum number of digits (17) exceeded.')));
                            });
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              userQuestion = userAnswer;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.teal[300],
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }

                    // Rest of the buttons
                    else {
                      return MyButton(
                          buttonTapped: () {
                            if (userQuestion.length >= 17) {
                              setState(() {
                                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        'Maximum number of digits (17) exceeded.')));
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                userQuestion += buttons[index];
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          buttonText: buttons[index],
                          color: isOperator(buttons[index])
                              ? Colors.teal[300]
                              : Colors.teal,
                          textColor: Colors.white);
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isOperator(String x) {
    if (x == '%' || x == '/' || x == '×' || x == '-' || x == '+' || x == '=') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void equalPressed() {
    String finalQuestion = userQuestion;
    finalQuestion = finalQuestion.replaceAll('×', '*');
    finalQuestion = finalQuestion.replaceAll('%', '*0.01');
    finalQuestion = finalQuestion.replaceAll('÷', '/');

    Parser p = Parser();
    Expression exp = p.parse(finalQuestion);
    ContextModel cm = ContextModel();
    double eval = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);

    userAnswer = eval.toString();
  }
}
```

My problem is that, the GridView (and the last row of buttons at the bottom), are at the bottom of my screen. That is, on a smaller phone. I have tested the app on bigger phones and encountered, that the buttons are not at the bottom of the screen, they are in the middle. I have tried to change the flex value of the Expanded widget, I couldn't get it to work tho. I also have tried to take the phone's screen height (in pixels), calculate 3/4 of it (that is the space which the second/lower Expanded widget takes up, because I have specified that Flex = 3 in the lower/second Expanded widget. Then I took the value (3/4 of the screen's height) and subtracted the space which the buttons take up. The new value I got was passed in a SizedBox above the lower/second Expanded, in order to push the buttons to the bottom. unfortunately, that didn't work. Does anybody have an idea of how I could get this to work?[image][image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of actual view and a picture of desired layout?

Comment: @suztomo The upper one is how I want it to look, the lower one is how it looks in big phones.

Comment: If I interpret your explanation correctly, you are looking for a way to push a widget to the bottom of the screen. The calculator buttons are irrelevant (they are the same as just a simple Container widget). Am I correct?

Comment: @suztomo, you are correct yes

Comment: Good. I think Rohit’s answer should work. If not, you may want to simplify the code in question so that it only has a red box (Container). A red box as in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: Reverse the Column, so you are drawing the buttons first, which will fit flush to the bottom of the screen, and let the top Expand to fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove Expanded around GridView
2. Use `shrinkWrap` inside GridView ([docs on shrinkWrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html))

And see if this gives you the desired effect.  (Leave the other Expanded or Flexible in place so entire screen height is used.):

```
          GridView.builder(
            // ↑ not wrapped in Flexible/Expanded
            // ↓ try shrinkWrap for your Gridview
            shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: buttons.length,
```

`shrinkWrap` shouldn't be overly expensive since you aren't actually scrolling the GridView with many items and its being used simply as a convenient layout widget.

Larger code snippet to help orient where the above code is changed:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal[100],
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(userQuestion,
                        style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.teal[900])),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      userAnswer,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.teal[900]),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GridView.builder(
            // ↑ not wrapped in Flexible/Expanded
            // ↓ this is new
            shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: buttons.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 4),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                // Clear Button
                if (index == 0) {
                  return MyButton(
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed it.

Comment: Awesome.  Constraints and layout in Flutter are not very straight forward, in my opinion.  If you're interested in reading more / seeing tons of examples of how to work with layout & constraints: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 0):

From the body column, wrap it with safe area widget.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: But why? @Shubhamhackz I want to change the lower Expanded widget, not everything

Comment: That didn't work and didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have got two options here.

Either use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get the device-screen height and then modify the button-height accordingly 
 or 
Just align the container in the lower expanded widget to the bottom center or something.
For example: `Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Container(...))`

Comment: Unfortunately `Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Container(...))` didn't work. As I don't have a set height for my buttons, I will redo the button class so I can pass in a `height: ` parameter, in order to sync the UI on different devices.